# Logic not working - matching values with ages in a list

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am trying to match particular values (`val_A`) to ages I have in a list (`val_B`) in csv format.

I am using the below Python code but it's never meeting the first two criteria.

The last two `elif` and the `else` statements are working, and almost always the `else` criteria is applied.

```
def age_convert(val_A):
    val_B = 1
    ages = pd.read_csv('age.csv')
    #print(ages)

    if val_A in ages:
        val_B = val_A
    elif val_A>91:
        val_B=91
    elif val_A<0:
        val_B=val_A*-1
    elif val_A==86:
        val_B=val_A+2
    else:
        val_B=val_A+1
        print('I went through the else')

    return val_B

test = age_convert(1)

print(test)
```

Comment: Are you sure the read_csv is giving you integers, as opposed to, say, strings?

Comment: could you show us the result of `pd.read_csv('age.csv')`?

Comment: @aghast it seems like this actually might be the issue

Comment: @ted  please see below:
unique ages
0          91.0
1          90.0
2          89.0
3          88.0
4          85.0
5          84.0
6          82.0
7          81.0
8          80.0
9          78.0
10         77.0
11         76.0
12         75.0
13         74.0
14         73.0
15         72.0
16         71.0
17         70.0
18         69.0
19         68.0
20         67.0
21         66.0
22         65.0
23         64.0
24         63.0
25         62.0
26         61.0
27         60.0
28         59.0
29         58.0
..          ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to cast the values eplicitly to `Integer`?

Anyway, it seems that it's not the best approach to check if a value is in a DataFrame, as the elements that are "in" the DF are the column names. Instead of that check if it's in df.values:

```py
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0  10  11  12  13
>>> 'A' in df
True
>>> 10 in df
False
>>> 10 in df.values
True
```